# How to create a new Chainlink price feed

Tags: chainlink

As far as I've seen, the Chainlink docs do not mention how to create a new Price Feed.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a network of Chainlink nodes together. This requires a network of different Chainlink node operators requesting and providing data on-chain from different off-chain sources.
2. *Recommended*: Reach out to the [Chainlink Labs](https://data.chain.link/) team to help facilitate creating new feed, or adding a feed to an existing network of nodes.
3. Find a network of existing node operators and ask them to provide data for a smart contract.